# Parse DateTime is C# alwas thread dependent

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse from diffrent languages. The problem is i get always the thread given language for parsing.

```
var lang = "en-US";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = lang;
var datetime = DateTime.Parse(fromdate, "en-EN");
```

Comment: Your code won't _even_ compile. `CurrentCulture` expects `CultureInfo` and `DateTime.Parse` expect `IFormatProvider` as a second parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = to null. Than your desired language. Works for me.